# QMdiSubWindow not accepting drops

Tags: qt, matplotlib, pyqt

I have this small QT program:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import sys

class QtZListView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QListView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.model = QtGui.QStringListModel(['a','b','c'])
        self.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)

    def setStringList(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.model.setStringList(*args, **kwargs)

class mplsubwindow(QtGui.QMdiSubWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QMdiSubWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("testing")
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100, 
                     facecolor = self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Background).name()
        )
        p = FigureCanvas(fig)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.hold(False)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(
            self,
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        fig.tight_layout()
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar(p, self)
        self.layout().addWidget(toolbar)
        self.layout().addWidget(p)
        self.resize(400,400)
        self.show()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print('entering')
        super(mplsubwindow, self).dragEnterEvent(event)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        print('drag moving')
        super(mplsubwindow, self).dragMoveEvent(event)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print('dropped')
        super(mplsubwindow, self).dropEvent(event)

class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        mainwid = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        mainwid.setLayout(layout)
        self.mdiarea = QtGui.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(mainwid)
        layout.addWidget(self.mdiarea)
        sub = mplsubwindow(self.mdiarea)
        fig = Figure()
        p = FigureCanvas(fig)
        sub.layout().addWidget(p)
        sub.show()
        layout.addWidget(QtZListView())

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to be able to drag one or more items from the list in the bottom into the matplotlib canvas. For some reason only the enter-event is invoked...the remaining drag/drop events seems to be ignored...and furthermore it seems like the QMdiSubWindow does not accept drops even though i set setAcceptDrops(True). 
What am I missing here?

Comment: As I just discovered while [answering your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35983425/1994235), bypassing `QMdiSubWindow.setWidget()` and using the layout directly is a bad idea! One of the things `setWidget` does is install an event filter (if you look at the C++ source code). I suspect the drag/drop behaviour will work if you use `setWidget()` as in the above linked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept the event in the `dragEnterEvent` method or else move and drop events are ignored.

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
    print('entering')
    event.accept()
    super(mplsubwindow, self).dragEnterEvent(event)
```

Note that I really want to emphasise you should be adding the widget via `QMdiSubWindow.setWidget()`. Any of the other methods (like using `QMdiSubWindow.layout()` or `QMdiSubWindow.setCentralWidget()`) are **not fully supported by MDI windows** and will likely lead to other issues down the road. If you feel that `setWidget()` is not doing what you want, ask a new question detailing the issue so that it can be resolved while still using `setWidget()`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this